# How to load htm file from URL?

Tags: iphone

I need to load url in UIWebview in iPhone. But the url is htm format. So, the url doesn't load in UIWebview.

I used the following url, as parsing : http://feeds.epicurious.com/latestfeatures and I get image url as a htm format.

The image URL is `http://feedads.g.doubleclick.net/~at/-0LKpwQCz1qAqaaMSvxTK4I9PjA/0/di`.

There is a way to load this URL in UIWebview.

Is there another possible way to load that url in UIImageview? If there is a any way, to load UIImageview, it also OK for me.

I used the following code:

```
UIView* testView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)] autorelease];
UIWebView* testWebView = [[[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)] autorelease];
[testView addSubview:testWebView];
[testWebView setDelegate:self];
[testWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://feedads.g.doubleclick.net/~at/K_fHnmr7a7T0pru2TjQC29TsPYY/1/di"]]];
[self.view addSubview:testView];
```

My URL page is:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I opened that url in my browser and all i saw was a white/transparent 1x1 pixel image. Are you sure this isn't a joke or you don't want to increase your ad turnover with a little help from stackoverflow users?

Comment: No, Dominik.. you misunderstand me... i attached the screenshot now..  see the screenshot now.. i need to load that animated image in my iphone...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a reason why that URL would not load in a UIWebView.

You should be able to use code similar to this:

```
NSString *url = @"http://feedads.g.doubleclick.net/~at/K_fHnmr7a7T0pru2TjQC29TsPYY/1/di";
[myWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]]]
```

Comment: I used code like as following.....But the URL is not loading.... UIView* testView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)] autorelease];
 UIWebView* testWebView = [[[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)] autorelease];
 [testView addSubview:testWebView];
 [testWebView setDelegate:self];
 [testWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://feedads.g.doubleclick.net/~at/K_fHnmr7a7T0pru2TjQC29TsPYY/1/di"]]];
 [self.view addSubview:testView];

Comment: Can you put that code in a code block in your original question? It's very difficult to read code embedded in comments.